# If Else in Postman based on response body

Tags: json, if-statement, postman

In postman, if i get a responsebody of [] i want to do an "IF" statement but if the response is anything else it will do the "ELSE" statement however, i cannot make it do the "IF" suggesting that *jsonData == "[]"* is wrong.

[image: postman capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Your response is an array, not a String, so you cann't compare `jsonData == "[]"`

**Solution**

Check this array whether has length = 0 or not, you can choose one of 2 below approaches.

```
if (Array.isArray(jsonData) && jsonData.length === 0)
```

or

```
if (Array.isArray(jsonData) && !jsonData.length)
```

Comment: Adding an additional check like `Array.isArray(arr)` might be useful, as `.length` could be used on other datatypes.

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks. Based on assumption, String won't be parsed successfully from `JSON.parse()` or `pm.response.json()` then I don't check type `array`. Anw, I've updated my answer.